# Format input currency jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems creating the mask for the currency field.

1- I need to limit UP TO 18 characters (counting the '.' and the ',') Ex: 999.999.999.999,99

2 - I need you to put more than one '.' (currently only one)

3 - I need this not to happen:

[image]

Because when I type it adds the '.' right then before I type in one more number.

My code:

```js
function onlyNumberAmount(input) {
    var v = input.value;
    v = v + '';
    v = parseInt(v.replace(/[\D]+/g, ''));
    v = v + '';
    v = v.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
    v = v.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");
    input.value = v;
    if(v == 'NaN') input.value = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mP0"  onkeyup="onlyNumberAmount(this)">
```

Comment: what if you format the value on blur ?

Comment: @Dani I need it to be a keyup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to meet your requirements.

```js
function onlyNumberAmount(input) {
  let v = input.value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
  if (v.length > 14) v = v.slice(0, 14);
  input.value =
    v.replace(/(\d)(\d\d)$/, "$1,$2")
     .replace(/(^\d{1,3}|\d{3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:,|$))/g, '$1.');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="mP0" onkeyup="onlyNumberAmount(this)">
```

`\d` is short for `[0-9]` as I'm sure you know.

A positive lookahead `(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:,|$))` is used to ensure the correct placement of the `.`

`14` is the maximum number of digits that can appear in the string.

Further explanation on request.

Comment: Thaaaaaaanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If, test if the field is already valid

```
const moneyTest = /(\d{1,3}\.)?(\d{1,3}\.)?(\d{1,3})?(.\d{1,2})?/

if (!moneyTest.test(field)) {
```

Then, if it's not, separate into the number fields

```
var digits = /d/g.match(field); // might be field.match(/d/g)
```

Now you have to see if there was a decimal place in the original number

```
var dot = field.lastIndexOf(".");
```

And then you should be good to reconstruct the number.

Question: What happens if there are two dots?

Comment: It can go up to 3 dots. EX: 9.999.999.999,00

Comment: @SallyNeves So switch the dots and commas in my regex and the lastindexof. But then what happens if you have multiple commas?